# Does the date() function have any arguments?

Tags: r

I tried to find whether it has one, but there seems to be none in help.

```
help(date)
```

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't have any arguments. `date()`:

> Returns a character string of the current system date and time.

Are you looking for `as.Date()` ?

`apropos("(^|\\.)date")` will show you all the currently available functions (i.e., in base R) that either start with "date"` or have a dot followed by "date" (case-insensitive):

```
[1] "-.Date"             ".Date"              "[.Date"            
 [4] "[[.Date"            "[<-.Date"           "+.Date"            
 [7] "as.character.Date"  "as.data.frame.Date" "as.Date"           
[10] "as.Date.character"  "as.Date.default"    "as.Date.factor"    
[13] "as.Date.numeric"    "as.Date.POSIXct"    "as.Date.POSIXlt"   
[16] "as.list.Date"       "as.POSIXct.Date"    "as.POSIXlt.Date"   
[19] "axis.Date"          "c.Date"             "cut.Date"          
[22] "date"               "diff.Date"          "format.Date"       
[25] "is.numeric.Date"    "julian.Date"        "length<-.Date"     
[28] "Math.Date"          "mean.Date"          "months.Date"       
[31] "Ops.Date"           "print.Date"         "quarters.Date"     
[34] "rep.Date"           "round.Date"         "seq.Date"          
[37] "split.Date"         "summary.Date"       "Summary.Date"      
[40] "Sys.Date"           "trunc.Date"         "weekdays.Date"     
[43] "xtfrm.Date"
```